# how to prefill form data to update in next js with typescript and redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, react-redux, redux-toolkit

i completed crud a project with react and redux toolkit.now i want to implement next js and typescript with the same project.when i wanted to prefill form data using uselocation hook there is showing an error. please someone help me. github link-- https://github.com/arshad007hossain/nex-typescript-crud-app

bookslice.ts

```
import { PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
const { createSlice } = require("@reduxjs/toolkit");
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid'
import { RootState } from "../store";

type Book = {
  id: string
  title: string
  author: string
}

type initialState = {
  books: Book[];
}

const initialState: initialState = {
  books: [
    { id: uuidv4(), title: "new programmar", author: "john smith" },
    { id: uuidv4(), title: "Connecting the dot", author: "john smith" },
  ],
};

export const booksSlice = createSlice({
  name: "books",
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {
    showBooks: (state) => state,
    addBook: (state, action: PayloadAction<Book[]>) => {
      state.books.push(action.payload);
      // state.countBooks = state.countBooks + 1;
      toast.success("New Book Added");
    },
    updateBook: (state, action:PayloadAction<Book>) => {
      const { id, title, author } = action.payload;
      const isBookExist = state.books.filter((book) => book.id === id);
      if (isBookExist) {
        isBookExist[0].title = title;
        isBookExist[0].author = author;
        toast.info("Book Updated");
      }
    },
    deleteBook: (state, action:PayloadAction<Book>) => {
      const id = action.payload;
      state.books = state.books.filter((book) => book.id !== id);
      // state.countBooks = state.countBooks - 1;
      toast.warn("Book Deleted");
    },
  },
});

export const { showBooks, addBook, deleteBook, updateBook } =
  booksSlice.actions;


export const getAllBooks = (state: RootState) => state.books


export default booksSlice.reducer;
```

addBook.tsx

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useAppDispatch } from "../hooks";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { addBook } from "../slices/bookSlice";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

const AddBook = () => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();
  const router = useRouter();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onSubmit = ({ title, author }) => {
    const book = { id: uuidv4(), title, author };
    dispatch(addBook(book));
    router.push("/showBooks");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ToastContainer/>
      <h2 className="text-center">Add Books</h2>
      <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <div className="mb-3">
            <label htmlFor="text" className="form-label">
              Title
            </label>
            <input
              {...register("title", { required: "Title is required" })}
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
            />
            {errors.title?.type === "required" && "Title is required" && (
        <p style={{ color: "red" }}>Title is Required.</p>
    )}
          </div>
          <div className="mb-3">
            <label htmlFor="text" className="form-label">
              Author
            </label>
            <input
              {...register("author", { required: "Author is required" })}
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
            />
            {errors.author?.type === "required" && "Author  is required" && (
        <p style={{ color: "red" }}>Author is Required.</p>
    )}
          </div>

          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
            Add Book
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddBook;
```

editBook.tsx

when i try use uselocation this error occurs:
useLocation() may be used only in the context of a  component.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { updateBook } from "../slices/bookSlice";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";

const EditBook = ({state}) => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();
  const location = useLocation();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const router = useRouter();
  const [id] = useState(location.state.id);

  console.log(location.state.title)
  console.log(location.state.author)
  
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(location.state.title);
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState(location.state.author);

  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    dispatch(updateBook({ id, title, author }));
    router.push("/showBooks");
  };
  return (
    
    <div>
      <ToastContainer/>
      <h1 className="text-center">Edit Book</h1>
      <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <div className="mb-3">
            <label htmlFor="text" className="form-label">
              Title
            </label>
            <input
              {...register("title", { required: "Title is required" })}
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
            />
            {errors.title?.type === "required" && "Title is required" && (
        <p style={{ color: "red" }}>Title is Required.</p>
    )}
          </div>
          <div className="mb-3">
            <label htmlFor="text" className="form-label">
              Author
            </label>
            <input
              {...register("author", { required: "Author is required" })}
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
            />
            {errors.author?.type === "required" && "Author  is required" && (
        <p style={{ color: "red" }}>Author is Required.</p>
    )}
          </div>

          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
            Update Book
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default EditBook;
```

showBooks.tsx

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import Link from "next/link";
import React from "react";
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from "../hooks";
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import { deleteBook, getAllBooks } from "../slices/bookSlice";

const BooksView = () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const AllBooks = useAppSelector(getAllBooks);
  // const count = useAppSelector(selectCount);
  // const numberOfBooks = useAppSelector((state) => state
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const handleDeleteBook = (id) => {
    dispatch(deleteBook(id));
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h2 className="text-center">List of Books</h2>
      {/* <h2>There are {numberOfBooks} Books</h2> */}
      <table className="table table-striped table-border w-50 align-center m-auto">
        <thead  className="text-center">
          <tr>
            {/* <th>ID</th> */}
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody className="text-center">
          {AllBooks.books.map((book) => {
            const { id, title, author } = book;
            return (
              <tr key={id}>
                {/* <td>{id}</td> */}
                <td>{title}</td>
                <td>{author}</td>
                <td>
                  <Link href="/editBook">
                  <button className="btn btn-primary mx-2">Edit</button>
                  </Link>
                  <button className="btn btn-info"
                    onClick={() => {
                      handleDeleteBook(id);
                    }}
                  >
                    Delete
                  </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BooksView;
```

Comment: Does editBook.tsx live in the same router as the other files (wherever your routes live. I.e. App.js)? The useLocation error you're getting usually only happens when the target file is outside of the router context

Comment: i did not use router in next js before.so i dont know where to add this BrowserRouter

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't tell your entire story.

Comment: yes.my all files are in same folder.